# Are "id" and "name" the same in Elixir Supervisor/Process?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I created a Supervisor named `ElectionManager.Application` and a worker.
Then I looked at the information of those processes:

```
iex(3)> proc = Process.whereis(ElectionManager.Application)
#PID<0.158.0>

iex(4)> Process.info proc
[registered_name: ElectionManager.Application,
 current_function: {:gen_server, :loop, 7},
 initial_call: {:proc_lib, :init_p, 5}, status: :waiting, message_queue_len: 0,
 messages: [], links: [#PID<0.156.0>, #PID<0.159.0>],
 dictionary: ["$initial_call": {:supervisor, Registry.Supervisor, 1},
  "$ancestors": [#PID<0.156.0>]], trap_exit: true,
 error_handler: :error_handler, priority: :normal, group_leader: #PID<0.155.0>,
 total_heap_size: 986, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 10, reductions: 339,
 garbage_collection: [max_heap_size: %{error_logger: true, kill: true, size: 0},
  min_bin_vheap_size: 46422, min_heap_size: 233, fullsweep_after: 65535,
  minor_gcs: 2], suspending: []]

iex(7)> {id, child, type, modules} = Supervisor.which_children(proc) |> List.first
{ElectionManager.Application.PIDPartition0, #PID<0.159.0>, :worker,
 [Registry.Partition]}

iex(8)> Process.info child
[registered_name: ElectionManager.Application.PIDPartition0,
 current_function: {:gen_server, :loop, 7},
 initial_call: {:proc_lib, :init_p, 5}, status: :waiting, message_queue_len: 0,
 messages: [], links: [#PID<0.158.0>, #PID<0.156.0>],
 dictionary: ["$initial_call": {Registry.Partition, :init, 1},
  "$ancestors": [ElectionManager.Application, #PID<0.156.0>]], trap_exit: true,
 error_handler: :error_handler, priority: :normal, group_leader: #PID<0.155.0>,
 total_heap_size: 233, heap_size: 233, stack_size: 10, reductions: 47,
 garbage_collection: [max_heap_size: %{error_logger: true, kill: true, size: 0},
  min_bin_vheap_size: 46422, min_heap_size: 233, fullsweep_after: 65535,
  minor_gcs: 0], suspending: []]
```

in the Elixir document, the differences between `name` and `child_id` wasn't clear, and there seems a `id: something` option for workers and `name: something` option for processes and Supervisors. I am confused.
From above, it seems that `id` and `registered_name` are the same.

I want to have my Supervisor to supervise multiple children, but I cannot do that by default (I get the `:already_started` error). Should I change both the name and the id, or only either?

Comment: What I Understood is you are trying to create the process with the same registered name. Just take out that part.
I think your are defining the `genserver` your childprocess to supervise with name option something like `GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [],[name: __MODULE__])` if that is the case then remove that because you are trying to create the multiple process and you are trying to register all of them with the same name.

Comment: make sure that your child process server which is to be supervised should be `Genserver.start_link(__MODULE__,[],[])` as you are creating the multiple kid process on that server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The id is just an internal identifier used only by the supervisor of a worker. It has to be unique for all workers in the same supervisor.

The name is the value that you can address a process with, instead of using its PID.

The reason you're seeing the same values for the name and the id is that the supervisor uses the name of the process for the worker id by default.

Answer (score 0):

The name has nothing to do with supervisor. A process name is used to find the process when you want to refer to it, supervised or unsupervised.

The process id is an internal identifier BEAM uses for processes, just like your OS gives each process an id. Supervisor captures this id to be able to monitor and restart it later.

The child id you give to supervisor, is used to save children spec. If you don't provide it explicitly, it is the name of module that is used to start the child. It can be later used to retrieve the child spec.

If you want to start multiple children using the same module, you have to explicitly specify the child id, since two children can not have the same id (consider the children spec as a hash map of child_id => child_spec).

If you need to start multiple children using the same module, maybe you are looking for [`simple_one_to_one`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-strategies) strategy of supervisor. Using this, you specify your spec once, and request the supervisor to start the children at run time (as apposed to others where the children are started on boot).

Comment: This is a little inaccurate, the process id is not the same thing as a PID, which is what the BEAM uses internally to address your processes. The process id that the supervisor uses will be different.

Comment: @narrowtux Can you explain a bit more? When you start a worker under a supervisor, you have to return `{:ok, pid}`, and this `pid` should be the process being supervised, aka the child. This is the internal identifier of the process, that BEAM generates and supervisor uses. What is the difference?

Comment: Ok I shouldn't have said inaccurate but it's a little misleading because when you give your process a name, Supervisor will use that name as the id to track the process.

Comment: @narrowtux Supervisor does use pid to track if a child is alive or not. Reading https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/supervisor.erl, lines 363 and and 622 confirms that supervisor saves child's pid, and uses that when restarting the child. Anything I am missing?